# Why do I get dir: command not found on Mac when there is some files in that directory?

Tags: command-line, terminal, directory, command-line-interface

I try to see the files that are in my Desktop. So I move into the directory of my desktop. Then I write: dir in Terminal and it says:
-bash: dir: command not found
What could possibly be the problem? Because obviously there are many files there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `dir` is either not a bash command on your MacOS, or it's not in your PATH variable.

Try this: `alias dir=ls`

It isn't elegant (a function would really be better), but it may help.

Comment: It seems like "ls" is the same as "dir" for Mac and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @fof `ls` is the standard command for listing directories on all flavors of Unix. `dir` is a Windows command.